# Alfa AWUS1900 driver support

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, alfa-wireless

I recently purchased [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MZD7Z76) wireless card for my desktop and am having trouble getting it to work on Linux. Is this card supported on the latest kernel version? I have installed the drivers but still does not seem to be working. Would someone be able to tell me if I went wrong in a step?

I downloaded the drivers from [here](https://github.com/xxNull-lsk/rtl8812AU/tree/a88cb341d021b58397307a144b1af1d9941da5c0) ran the commands manually per the README but still no luck, below are the steps I took on my machine.

```
linx@linx-System-Product-Name:~/rtl8812AU$ make
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build M=/home/linx/rtl8812AU  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-40-generic'
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_cmd.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_security.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_debug.o
/home/linx/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_debug.c: In function ‘dump_drv_version’:
/home/linx/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_debug.c:50:62: warning: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Wdate-time]
RTW_PRINT_SEL(sel, "build time: %s %s\n", __DATE__, __TIME__);
                                                          ^
/home/linx/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_debug.c:50:62: warning: macro "__TIME__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Wdate-time]
/home/linx/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_debug.c:50:62: warning: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Wdate-time]
/home/linx/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_debug.c:50:62: warning: macro "__TIME__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Wdate-time]
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_io.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_ioctl_query.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_ioctl_set.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_ieee80211.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_mlme.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_mlme_ext.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_mi.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_wlan_util.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_vht.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_pwrctrl.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_rf.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_recv.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_sta_mgt.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_ap.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_xmit.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_p2p.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_tdls.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_br_ext.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_iol.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_sreset.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_btcoex.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_beamforming.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_odm.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/core/efuse/rtw_efuse.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/os_dep/osdep_service.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/os_dep/linux/usb_intf.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/os_dep/linux/usb_ops_linux.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/os_dep/linux/ioctl_linux.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/os_dep/linux/xmit_linux.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/os_dep/linux/mlme_linux.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/os_dep/linux/recv_linux.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/os_dep/linux/rtw_cfgvendor.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/os_dep/linux/wifi_regd.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/os_dep/linux/rtw_android.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/os_dep/linux/rtw_proc.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/os_dep/linux/ioctl_mp.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/hal_intf.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/hal_com.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/hal_com_phycfg.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/hal_phy.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/hal_dm.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/hal_btcoex.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/hal_mp.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/hal_mcc.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/hal_hci/hal_usb.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/led/hal_usb_led.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/HalPwrSeqCmd.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/rtl8812a/Hal8812PwrSeq.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/rtl8812a/Hal8821APwrSeq.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_xmit.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_sreset.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_hal_init.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_phycfg.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_rf6052.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_dm.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_rxdesc.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_cmd.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/rtl8812a/usb/usb_halinit.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/rtl8812a/usb/rtl8812au_led.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/rtl8812a/usb/rtl8812au_xmit.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/rtl8812a/usb/rtl8812au_recv.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/rtl8812a/usb/usb_ops_linux.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/efuse/rtl8812a/HalEfuseMask8812A_USB.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/rtl8812a/hal8812a_fw.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/phydm/phydm_debug.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/phydm/phydm_antdiv.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/phydm/phydm_antdect.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/phydm/phydm_interface.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/phydm/phydm_hwconfig.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/phydm/phydm.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/phydm/halphyrf_ce.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/phydm/phydm_edcaturbocheck.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/phydm/phydm_dig.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/phydm/phydm_pathdiv.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/phydm/phydm_rainfo.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/phydm/phydm_dynamicbbpowersaving.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/phydm/phydm_powertracking_ce.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/phydm/phydm_dynamictxpower.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/phydm/phydm_adaptivity.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/phydm/phydm_cfotracking.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/phydm/phydm_noisemonitor.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/phydm/phydm_acs.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/phydm/phydm_beamforming.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/phydm/phydm_dfs.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/phydm/txbf/halcomtxbf.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/phydm/txbf/haltxbfinterface.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/phydm/txbf/phydm_hal_txbf_api.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/phydm/phydm_kfree.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/phydm/phydm_ccx.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/phydm/rtl8812a/halhwimg8812a_fw.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/phydm/rtl8812a/halhwimg8812a_mac.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/phydm/rtl8812a/halhwimg8812a_bb.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/phydm/rtl8812a/halhwimg8812a_rf.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/phydm/rtl8812a/halphyrf_8812a_ce.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/phydm/rtl8812a/phydm_regconfig8812a.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/phydm/rtl8812a/phydm_rtl8812a.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/hal/phydm/txbf/haltxbfjaguar.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/platform/platform_ops.o
      CC [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_mp.o
      LD [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/8812au.o
      Building modules, stage 2.
      MODPOST 1 modules
      CC      /home/linx/rtl8812AU/8812au.mod.o
      LD [M]  /home/linx/rtl8812AU/8812au.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-40-generic'

$ sudo make install
install -p -m 644 8812au.ko  /lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/kernel/drivers  /net/wireless/
/sbin/depmod -a 4.10.0-40-generic
$ sudo modprobe -a 8812au
```

$lsusb output for card

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:8813 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.'
```

Thanks for any help! Let me know if I should post some more information, first time posting here.

Comment: Will you please paste the Makefile and also the result of: `modinfo 8812au | grep 8813` Paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com Possible hint to chili: zebulon2.

Answer (score 3):

This driver works ok: https://github.com/zebulon2/rtl8814au

INSTALATION:

```
git clone https://github.com/zebulon2/rtl8814au.git
cd rtl8814au
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8814au
```